# How can I run parallel tests with appium using selenium grid?

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, appium, selenium-grid

I tried up two different appium servers in my machine and start tests for iOS in one server and start Android tests in other. I tried execute too in two servers to tests in different iOS.

But problem is when I execute to two iOS the tests that should happen in iOS1 are happen in iOS to, not always, have times that run on iOS1 and shuffle and then are executed on iOS2, when not, all run into clutter. Then I can't do execute tests in parallel in this format.

For Android + iOS, only tests to iOS make do.

How can I execute my tests in parallel using appium with Ruby, if not possible running in parallel how can I run in line?

Comment: Speaking of Appium with ruby, are you using Cucumber-Gherkin-Ruby set-up?

Comment: @VighneshPai, I'm using this set

Answer (score 2):

You need proper capabilities definition and request.

From my bit old notes (unfortunately for Android):

Stop/kill Selenium Server, all Appium instances and all tests (Ruby/Cucumber).

Start Selenium Server

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.6.0.jar -role hub
```

Save `SM_G900F.json` :

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "applicationName":"SM_G900F",
      "browserName":"android",
      "deviceName":"SM_G900F",
      "version":"7.0",
      "maxInstances":1,
      "platform":"Android"
    }
  ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "cleanUpCycle":2000,
    "timeout":30000,
    "proxy":"org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "url":"http://127.0.0.1:80801/wd/hub",
    "maxSession":6,
    "port":"80801",
    "bootstrap-port":"80802",
    "host": "localhost",
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hubPort": "4444",
    "hubHost": "localhost"
  }
}
```

Make sure to change `80801` and `80802` to free ports for each device!

Run appium:

```
appium --nodeconfig /path_to/SM_G900F.json -p 80801 --default-capabilities '{"udid":"BOGAA1BBB412"}'
```

Where udid is what `adb devices` gives you and again change `80801`

Check if device is registered correctly on http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/console

And finally in ruby:

```
require 'appium_lib'
opts_dut = {
    caps: {
        platformName: :android,
        version: '7.0',
        deviceName: '*',
        appPackage: 'your.package',
        appActivity: 'your.MainActivity',
        noReset: true,
        autoLaunch: false,
        automationName: 'uiautomator2'
    },
    appium_lib: {
        server_url: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
        wait_timeout: 300,
        wait_interval: 100,
        newCommandTimeout: 3000
    }
}
@T = Appium::Driver.new(opts_dut, true).start_driver
@T.find_elements(:uiautomator, "new UiSelector().textMatches(\"(?is).*SEND.*\"))")
puts @T.page_source
@T.quit
```

If I remember well requesting `deviceName` and/or `version` only works well. So if you start multiple nodes and specify `deviceName` and `version` correctly, you can then request it multiple time even in parallel. If you use wildcard `*` as in example above, it means any `deviceName`, so only `version` `7.0` is requested. Make sure run `@T.quit` to free device even if your test fail (put it in after hook).